# Avoiding duplication in FluentValidations

Tags: c#, .net, dry, fluentvalidation

I have a validator for a `CreateRequest` and another for `UpdateRequest`.

I soon discovered that they are the same. The only difference is that one has an Id (`UpdateRequest`).

The validations are the same, to the same properties, but the entities are different.

How can I avoid duplicating the rules?

Currently I have

```
public class CreateValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateRequest> 
{
     RuleFor(p => p.Prop1)...  // Rule 1
     RuleFor(p => p.Prop2)...  // Rule 2
     RuleFor(p => p.Prop3)...  // Rule 3
}

public class UpdateValidator : AbstractValidator<UpdateRequest> 
{
     RuleFor(p => p.Id)...     // Rule 0
     RuleFor(p => p.Prop1)...  // Rule 1
     RuleFor(p => p.Prop2)...  // Rule 2
     RuleFor(p => p.Prop3)...  // Rule 3
}
```

They are the same except for the Rule 0.

Can I avoid duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that your `CreateRequest` and `UpdateRequest` implement the same interface of are inherited from some base class(or one from another).

   ```
   public CreateRequest: Request{...}
   public UpdateRequest: Request{...}
   ```
2. Create a generic validator class with restricted generic type parameter.

   ```
   public RequestValidator: AbstractValidator<T> where T: Request
   {
       RequestValidator()
       {
            RuleFor(p => p.Prop1)...  // Rule 1
            RuleFor(p => p.Prop2)...  // Rule 2
            RuleFor(p => p.Prop3)...  // Rule 3
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create actual validator using inheritance.

   ```
   public CreateRequestValidator: RequestValidator<CreteRequest>
   {
       CreateRequestValidator()
       { }
   }
   public UpdateRequestValidator: RequestValidator<UpdateRequest>
   {
       UpdateRequestValidator()
       {
            RuleFor(p => p.Id)...           
       }
   }
   ```